# What is a good derivation for the formula $U=\frac{3}{2}nrT$?

Tags: energy, ideal-gas

I've recently learned that the internal energy of an ideal and monoatomic gas (under relevant assumptions) is equal to $\frac{3}{2}nrT$ or $\frac{3}{2}Nk_bT$ where r is the ideal gas constant and $k_b$ is the Boltzmann constant. However, I am unsure of what assumptions I have to undertake. Do I have to assume every particle travels with the exact same velocity? Or that the particles only have either an x,y or z velocity-component?

Basically, what are the assumptions for this formula and a derivation of it as simple and solid as possible?

Comment: [Equipartition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

The result
$$\langle E\rangle =\frac{3}{2}k_BT$$
is one of the consequences of the [Equipartition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) theorem. It assumes that each atom in monatomic gas to be
$$E=\sum_{1}^3 \frac{1}{2}mv_i^2$$
The equipartition theorem is derived from the Boltzmann distribution which assumes thermal equilibrium. See the following for more detail [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution).